# Calculating the Linear Erosion Rate Between Two Rasters in R

Tags: raster, r, erosion

I am trying to determine differences in erosion rates based on vegetation type in wetlands.  I have two raster layers based on NDVI that allow me to assess broads changes in the vegetation over time.  My issue comes in that I'm not sure how to calculate linear rates of erosion at specific points along the rasters.  My thought was to try and create a transect that basically starts at the edge in the older raster and ends at the edge in the newer raster but I'm not sure how to do that when I don't necessarily have specific geographic coordinates I'm interested in.

Edited to include image example.  This raster was created by determining where land was lost between a raster from 2017 and one from 2019 (the yellow and red pixels).  I'm interested in knowing the linear distance between a point on the edge of the yellow and one on the edge of the green.
[image]

Comment: What is a "Linear Erosion Rate"? How is it defined and calculated? How do you calculate a "Linear Erosion Rate" given a coordinate and two NDVI rasters? If you don't have geographic coordinates you are interested in, what are you interested in?

Comment: @Spacedman So what I'm calling linear erosion rate is basically how quickly the edge of the wetland is retreating due to waves eroding it.  I have two rasters and I basically want to determine the distance between the perimeter of the land in the older raster and the perimeter of the land in the newer raster.  I guess I could use coordinates but I'm doing this analysis for a lot of individual islands and I wasn't sure if there was a more automatic way.

Comment: I suppose this may make more sense if we could see some of the maps in question. There's like "islands" of vegetation that are shrinking and you are interested in the speed (like metres per year or something) that the vegetation is recessing. So a simple area change calculation wouldn't work...

Comment: That picture really helps so I've retracted my close vote. However the problem looks really hard because the land is so fractured. If this was a single coastline or a few large islands with smooth coasts it might be easier, but there's so much noise here that automatically finding a "coastline" to measure is tricky. You may have to identify areas manually (by plotting parts and identifying lines using `locator` maybe?).

Comment: @Spacedman I had a feeling that was probably going to be the case.  Thank you for the tip using locator.